# How to check multiple keys in JsonPath

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to find an object in a JSON array using JsonPath.
Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "bpm": "766",
    "time": "20:14:57",
    "confidence": "0"
  },
  {
    "bpm": "766",
    "time": "20:14:57",
    "confidence": "0"
  },
  {
    "bpm": "767",
    "time": "20:14:33",
    "confidence": "0"
  }
]
```

I am using `SelectToken` with the following JsonPath query to try to find a JSON object using two keys `bpm` and `time`. There is supposed to be an `and` operator between `bpm` and `time`.

Here is my query:

`$.[?(@.bpm=='767',@.time=='20:14:33')]`

But I'm getting an error saying there is an unexpected character `,` after `'767'`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Newtonsoft's implementation of JsonPath, the `and` operator is a double ampersand `&&`, not a comma `,`.  Change your expression as shown below and it should work properly:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
var obj = array.SelectToken("$.[?(@.bpm=='767' && @.time=='20:14:33')]");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gpU56p